# Creating dummy shared object (.so) to depend on other shared objects

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm trying to create a shared object (.so) that will make it so, by including one shared object with `-lboost`, I implicitly include all the boost libraries.  Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
BOOST_LIBS="-lboost_date_time-gcc43-mt -lboost_filesystem-gcc43-mt"
  #truncated for brevity
g++ $BOOST_LIBS -shared -Wl,-soname,libboost.so.1 -o libboost.so.1.0
ln -si libboost.so.1.0 libboost.so.1
ln -si libboost.so.1 libboost.so
```

After placing all 3 created files (libboost.so libboost.so.1 libboost.so.1.0) in the same directory as all the boost libraries, I tried compiling a test program with it (which depends on `-lboost_date_time-gcc43-mt`):

```
g++ -lboost test.cpp
```

Doing this, I got the same undefined reference message as not having -lboost.  Having `-lboost_date_time-gcc43-mt works`, but that's too wordy :)  How do I get -lboost to automatically bring in the other shared libraries?

Comment: Update:  Running objdump -x libboost.so | grep NEEDED gives this:
   NEEDED               libboost_date_time-gcc43-mt-1_38.so.1.38.0
   NEEDED               libboost_filesystem-gcc43-mt-1_38.so.1.38.0
   NEEDED               /boot/develop/lib/x86/libstdc++.so
   NEEDED               libroot.so

(note that I'm running Haiku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Not really, anyway.

The linker is stripping out all of the symbol dependencies because the .so doesn't use them.

You can get around this, perhaps, by writing a [linker script](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/gnu-linker/simple-commands.html) that declares all of the symbols you need as `EXTERN()` dependencies. But this implies that you'll need to list all of the mangled names for the symbols you need. Not at all worth the effort, IMO.

Comment: Ah, so I guess I'd have to write some code that references every single symbol in the dependencies or, rather, use a sane approach that doesn't strip the dependencies?  Or is creating dummy .so's practically impossible?

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I suppose I'll just set up a convenient environment variable to drop in when building:  g++ $lboost alive.cpp

Comment: If you're not already using Makefiles, you should. You might also want to consider using an auto-configure tool. It'll make developing lots easier.

Comment: `--no-as-needed` fixed the issue I was having trying to create a dummy/stub shared library

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for creating a dummy '.so', but I do have something that will simplify your life... I highly suggest that you try using cross-platform make ([CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)). In CMake, linking against those libraries is easy:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.37 COMPONENTS date_time filesystem REQUIRED)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myexecutable ${myexecutable_SRCS}) 
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myexecutable ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The commands above, if placed in a "CMakeLists.txt" file, is all you need to:

1. Verify that Boost 1.37 or later is installed, with the "date_time" and "filesystem" libraries installed.
2. Create an executable named "myexecutable" from the sources listed in the corresponding variable.
3. Link the executable "myexecutable" against the boost "date_time" and "filesystem" libraries.

See also: [Why the KDE project switched to CMake](http://lwn.net/Articles/188693/).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, making one .so depend on all boost .so files is quite possible (but might not actually help you). I've just tried this:

```
$ export BOOST_ROOT=/home/ghost/Work/Boost/boost-svn
$ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libboost.so -o libboost.so $BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so
$ g++ -L . -I $BOOST_ROOT first.cpp -lboost -Wl,-R$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib ./a.out
```

And it did work. However, note that dancing with -R and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I don't know an way how you can include the path to Boost .so inside your libboost.so so that they are used both for linking and actually running the application. I can include rpath inside libboost.so just fine, but it's ignored when resolving symbols for the application.